# Permeation of ultrasound waves

Tags: waves

Ultrasound waves can either permeate through human body as when it's used for fetuses, or bounce back right away when it's used for obstacle avoidance.

Is frequency/or energy determination of this property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether ultrasound bounces back or penetrates an object depends on [acoustic impedance](https://radiopaedia.org/articles/acoustic-impedance) of the target compared to acoustic impedance of the medium the ultrasound passes through on its way to the target.

For example, the acoustic impedance of water is considerably less than the acoustic impedance of steel.  Sound waves penetrate water much more easily than they penetrate steel.  A large fraction of sound waves passing through the sea will bounce off the steel hull of a submarine back through lower-impedance water (unless the hull is covered with sound-absorbing membrane).

In medical imaging, ultrasound gel is applied to the skin in order to insure that the ultrasound doesn't pass through any low-impedance air and get reflected back from the skin as noise.  Once inside the body, ultrasound will tend to bounce off denser tissues with greater acoustic impedance than the softer tissues it may encounter on the way to the dense structures.

Acoustic impedance is determined by the density of the target and the speed of the sound wave:

**Z = d * c**, where **Z** is impedance, **d** is density, and **c** is speed.

The fraction of sound waves reflected back from an interface between two media can be calculated by the reflection fraction:

**[(Z2 - Z1) / (Z2 + Z1)]^2**

**Z2** is acoustic impedance of the target, and **Z1** is acoustic impedance of the intervening medium.

[Ultrasound equipment](https://www.howequipmentworks.com/ultrasound_basics/) consists of an array of piezoelectric crystals that both generate and listen to ultrasound waves.  The shape and density of targets determine the fraction of ultrasound waves reflected back to the crystal.